# JavaFX 8 WebView crashes app for some URLs after Sandbox is enabled

Tags: java, javafx, app-store, appstore-sandbox

I am using WebView to open a web page, nothing non-usual. For many web pages, there is no issues but for some it crashes the app, actually JVM crashes.

Reproduction steps:

**1 Create new Application class 'Test.java'**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            URL resource = Test.class.getResource("Test.fxml");
            loader.setLocation(resource);
            loader.setController(new TestController());
            BorderPane rootLayout = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout, 1200, 800);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        Platform.exit();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

**2 Create new Controller 'TestController.java' that loads the problematic URL**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class TestController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        webView.getEngine().load("http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/233053/why-were-default-and-static-methods-added-to-interfaces-in-java-8-when-we-alread");
    }
}
```

**3 Create XML with WebView 'Test.fxml'**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <WebView fx:id="webView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

**4 Create entitlement file 'entitlements.plist'**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>

    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>

</dict>
</plist>
```

**5 Apply entitlement**

I am using these commands:

```
chmod -R +w /Users/.../Test.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime
codesign -v -f -s $SIGNER --entitlements /Users/.../entitlements.plist /Users/.../Test.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime
find /Users/.../Test.app/Contents/ -type f \( -name "*.jar" -or -name "*.dylib" \) -exec codesign --verbose -f -s $SIGNER --entitlements /Users/.../Test/entitlements.plist {} \;
codesign -v -f -s $SIGNER --entitlements /Users/../entitlements.plist /Users/../Test.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jspawnhelper

codesign -v -f -s $SIGNER --entitlements /Users/../entitlements.plist /Users/ondrej/../Test.app
```

**Run the Test.app**

You will see that when WebView loads the URL, it shows the loaded page for a while then the application crashes.

I have tried to disable JavaScript, but it didn't help. App is still crashing.

Do you have any idea what might be the root-cause?

Here is the log from Mac Console: http://pastebin.com/wwXecvra

Comment: did you try it with 64bit jvm?

Comment: Yes. Here is exact versioning info: JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_72", OS_NAME="Darwin", OS_VERSION="11.2", OS_ARCH="x86_64"

Comment: Does it work with a slightly older version (e.g. 1.8.0_66)? WebView currently has some issues and with each version there are changes.

Comment: I have tried all Java 8 version from 51 to 72.